# How can I create a circle with a circles-border regularly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-photoshop-elements

I'm trying to make this:

[image]

But I don't know how should I create that circle-shape border?

Here is what I've tried so far .. But I've created those circles *(as border)* manually which aren't regullar:

[image]

Comment: I did it by using [the radius of circle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Teopi.png). Though I'm not sure my way has been the most standard approach.

Comment: Google Illustrator Blend tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make 15 lines / ticks with Photoshop, each of them rotated of 20°](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78286/make-15-lines-ticks-with-photoshop-each-of-them-rotated-of-20)

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in illustrator easily

1)Create a circle as a guide.
Add whatever shape you want to duplicate above the circle guide on a new layer

2) Highlights both shapes, then hit "R" to use the Rotation Tool. Hold "Alt" and click on the center of the guide circle. Make sure Preview is selected in the dialogue box. Make sure the number you enter can divide equally into 360.

3) Hit copy once you're happy with the placement on the shape. Then, hit "Ctrl+D" or "CMD+D" for Mac users to duplicate the shape around the circle.