# Make 15 lines / ticks with Photoshop, each of them rotated of 20°

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I would like to draw a few short lines, each of them rotated from the previous one of 20°, to do a **knob graduation** (here only 9 ticks). How to do this in Photoshop?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RotateMe script](http://blog.darkwark.com/rotateMe3/) is as close to Illustrator's `Effect > Distor & Transform > Transform` as you get with PS.

**The link seems to be down so code at the bottom of this answer ↓**

[image]

[image]

---

### Alternative method

Using **Transform again**, *Edit → Transform → Again* *( <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> )*

If you add `Alt` to the shortcut keys, it does "Duplicate again".

<sub><sup>I'm pretty sure I've used this since at least cs3.</sup></sub>

[image]

1. Free transform the object
2. Move reference point outside: hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> (this allows to move the reference point) and <kbd>Shift</kbd> (this allows to stay on a grid)
3. Rotate the amount you want
4. Undo
5. Transform again with <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Repeat as many times as is needed.

*Remark about step 2: Once the reference point has been moved at least once, then the black dot disappears in this 3x3 matrix, and then it's possible to use the input field to set a precise position for the reference point:*

[image]

---

> [KAM] RotateMe 3.jsx

Save it as plain text with the `.jsx`extension and then open it in Photoshop.

```js
@JSXBIN@ES@2.0@MyBbyBnAHMlKbyBn0ALblLn0ADJlLnASzLjTjUjBjSjUiSjBjEjJjVjTBAVzGjSjB
jEjJjVjTCfOnftJlMnASzJjFjOjEiSjBjEjJjVjTDBVCfOnftJlNnASzQjUjPjUjBjMiBjOjHjMjFiB
jNjPjVjOjUECnd2jIBftJlRnASzFjBjOjHjMjFFDCzBhPGVEfCVzFjTjUjFjQjTHfNnnnffJlUnASzF
jEjFjDjBjZIECGCzBhNJVBfAVDfBnnVHfNnnnffJlVnASCOVBfAnffJlYnASzJjMjBjZjFjSiTjJjaj
FKJEjzHjHjFjUiTjJjajFLfRBjzGjBiMjBjZjFjSMfffnffJlZnASCOCzBhLNnCGEXzDjNjBjYOfjzE
iNjBjUjIPfRCXzFjXjJjEjUjIQfVKfJXzGjIjFjJjHjIjURfVKfJffnndCnnntfOlbbldn0ACJldnAE
XzGjSjPjUjBjUjFSfjMfRBFdiaffJlenASzTjSjFjTjUjPjSjFiSjPjUjBjUjJjPjOiGjMjBjHTKnct
ffACzBhcUXQfVKfJXRfVKfJnnbymAn0ABJmAnASTKncfffOmEbmFn0ACJmFnASzKjMjBjZjFjSiHjSj
PjVjQVLEXzDjBjEjEWfXzJjMjBjZjFjSiTjFjUjTXfXzOjBjDjUjJjWjFiEjPjDjVjNjFjOjUYfjzDj
BjQjQZfnfnffJmGnABXzEjOjBjNjFgafVVfLCNCNCNXgafVzFjMjBjZjFjSgbfMnneChAhIVHfNnnnn
eIhAjDjPjQjJjFjThJnfAVzLjHjSjPjVjQiMjBjZjFjSjTgcfSnamJbmKn0AHJmKnASCOCJnVIfEnnn
tfJmLnASzGjDjPjPjSjEjTgdFEjzKjVjOjJjUiDjJjSjDjMjFgefRCVCfOCzBhKgfVFfDVzBjJhAfHn
nffnffJmNnASzIjOjFjXiMjBjZjFjShBIEXzJjEjVjQjMjJjDjBjUjFhCfjMfnfnffJmOnAEXzJjUjS
jBjOjTjMjBjUjFhDfVhBfIRCXzBhQhEfVgdfFXzBhRhFfVgdfFffJmPnABXgafVhBfICNCNCNXgafVg
bfMnneChAhICNVhAfHnndBnnnneBhJnfOmSbymTn0ABJmTnAEXSfVhBfIRBCNCgfVFfDVhAfHnnVzGj
EiBjOjHjMjFhGfPnnffAVzSjSjPjUjBjUjFiSjFjMjBjUjJjWjFiQjBjUjIhHfQbymVn0ABJmVnAEXS
fVhBfIRBCJVhGfPnndiaffOmZbyman0ABJmanAEXzEjNjPjWjFhIfVhBfIRCVVfLXzGiJiOiTiJiEiF
hJfjzQiFjMjFjNjFjOjUiQjMjBjDjFjNjFjOjUhKfffAVgcfSnAVhAfHAVHfNByBUOnAbynBn0ABJnB
nAEXSfjMfRBFdyiaffAVTfKnOnEbynFn0ABJnFnAEXzGjSjFjNjPjWjFhLfjMfnfAhzBhBhMVzMjTjB
jWjFiPjSjJjHjJjOjBjMhNfRnAThA4H0AiAH4B0AhAC4C0AhAhH4E0AhAhN4F0AhAgc4G0AhAgb40Bh
AhG4D0AhAB40BiAD4B0AiAE4C0AiAF4D0AiAI4E0AiAgd4F0AiAzGjDjJjSjDjMjFhO4G0AiAhB4I0A
iAK4J0AiAT4K0AiAV4L0AiAHMAzJjSjPjUjBjUjFiNjFhThPAnJMnMbyBn0AhDJnQnASzIjUjNjQiDj
PjMjPjShQAXzPjGjPjSjFjHjSjPjVjOjEiDjPjMjPjShRfjZfnftJnSnABXhRfjZfVzFjDjPjMjPjSh
SfSnfJnVnASzEjJjEiNjLhTBEjzOjDjIjBjSiJiEiUjPiUjZjQjFiJiEhUfRBFeEiNjLhAhAffnftJn
WnASzFjEjFjTjDhZhVCEjzQiBjDjUjJjPjOiEjFjTjDjSjJjQjUjPjShWfntnftJnXnASzGjJjEjOjV
jMjMhXDEjhUfRBFeEjOjVjMjMffnftJnYnASzEjSjFjGhXhYEEjzPiBjDjUjJjPjOiSjFjGjFjSjFjO
jDjFhZfntnftJnZnASzOjJjEjDjPjOjUjFjOjUiMjBjZjFjShaFEjzQjTjUjSjJjOjHiJiEiUjPiUjZ
jQjFiJiEhbfRBFeMjDjPjOjUjFjOjUiMjBjZjFjSffnftJnanAEXzIjQjVjUiDjMjBjTjThcfVhYfER
BVhafFffJnbnAEXzMjQjVjUiSjFjGjFjSjFjOjDjFhdfVhVfCRCVhXfDVhYfEffJncnASzGjJjEiVjT
jOjHheGEjhUfRBFeEiVjTjOjHffnftJndnASzGjJjEiUjZjQjFhfHEjhUfRBFeEiUjZjQjFffnftJne
nASzGjEjFjTjDhRhQiAIEjhWfntnftJnfnASzRjJjEjTjPjMjJjEiDjPjMjPjSiMjBjZjFjSiBJEjhb
fRBFePjTjPjMjJjEiDjPjMjPjSiMjBjZjFjSffnftJ2ABnAEXhcfViAfIRCVhffHViBfJffJ2BBnASz
FjJjEiTjIjQiCKEjhUfRBFeEiTjIjQhAffnftJ2CBnASzGjEjFjTjDhRhRiDLEjhWfntnftJ2DBnASz
FjJjEiUjPjQiEMEjhUfRBFeEiUjPjQhAffnftJ2EBnASzFjJjEiQjYjMiFNEjhUfRBFeEhDiQjYjMff
nftJ2FBnAEXzNjQjVjUiVjOjJjUiEjPjVjCjMjFiGfViDfLRDViEfMViFfNVzBjZiHfUffJ2GBnASzG
jJjEiMjFjGjUiIOEjhUfRBFeEiMjFjGjUffnftJ2HBnASiFNEjhUfRBFeEhDiQjYjMffnftJ2IBnAEX
iGfViDfLRDViIfOViFfNVzBjYiJfTffJ2JBnASzGjJjEiCjUjPjNiKPEjhUfRBFeEiCjUjPjNffnftJ
2KBnASiFNEjhUfRBFeEhDiQjYjMffnftJ2LBnAEXiGfViDfLRDViKfPViFfNCNViHfUVRfWnnffJ2MB
nASzGjJjEiSjHjIjUiLQEjhUfRBFeEiSjHjIjUffnftJ2NBnASiFNEjhUfRBFeEhDiQjYjMffnftJ2O
BnAEXiGfViDfLRDViLfQViFfNCNViJfTVQfVnnffJ2PBnASzGjJjEiFjMjQjTiMREjhUfRBFeEiSjDj
UjOffnftJ2QBnAEXzJjQjVjUiPjCjKjFjDjUiNfViAfIRDViCfKViMfRViDfLffJ2RBnAShaFEjhbfR
BFeMjDjPjOjUjFjOjUiMjBjZjFjSffnftJ2SBnAEXiNfVhVfCRDVhefGVhafFViAfIffJ2TBnAEjzNj
FjYjFjDjVjUjFiBjDjUjJjPjOiOfRDVhTfBVhVfCXzCiOiPiPfjzLiEjJjBjMjPjHiNjPjEjFjTiQff
fJ2XBnABXhRfjZfVhQfAnfZ2ZBnAXzLjBjDjUjJjWjFiMjBjZjFjSiRfXYfjZfAXhe4G0AiAQ4D0AhA
hf4H0AiAiA4I0AiAiJ4B0AhAiB4J0AiAiC4K0AiAiH4C0AhAiD4L0AiAiE4M0AiAiF4N0AiAiI4O0Ai
AiK4P0AiAiL4Q0AiAhQ40BiAiM4R0AiAhS40BhAhT4B0AiAhV4C0AiAhX4D0AiAhY4E0AiAR4E0AhAh
a4F0AiAFSAzNjEjSjBjXiSjFjDjUjBjOjHjMjFiSA2gaBM2gcBbyBn0AhDJ2hABnAShQAXhRfjZfnft
J2hCBnABXhRfjZfVhSfSnfJ2hFBnAShTBEjhUfRBFeEiNjLhAhAffnftJ2hGBnAShVCEjhWfntnftJ2
hHBnAShXDEjhUfRBFeEjOjVjMjMffnftJ2hIBnAShYEEjhZfntnftJ2hJBnAShaFEjhbfRBFeMjDjPj
OjUjFjOjUiMjBjZjFjSffnftJ2hKBnAEXhcfVhYfERBVhafFffJ2hLBnAEXhdfVhVfCRCVhXfDVhYfE
ffJ2hMBnASheGEjhUfRBFeEiVjTjOjHffnftJ2hNBnAShfHEjhUfRBFeEiUjZjQjFffnftJ2hOBnASi
AIEjhWfntnftJ2hPBnASiBJEjhbfRBFePjTjPjMjJjEiDjPjMjPjSiMjBjZjFjSffnftJ2hQBnAEXhc
fViAfIRCVhffHViBfJffJ2hRBnASiCKEjhUfRBFeEiTjIjQhAffnftJ2hSBnASiDLEjhWfntnftJ2hT
BnASiEMEjhUfRBFeEiUjPjQhAffnftJ2hUBnASiFNEjhUfRBFeEhDiQjYjMffnftJ2hVBnAEXiGfViD
fLRDViEfMViFfNViHfUffJ2hWBnASiIOEjhUfRBFeEiMjFjGjUffnftJ2hXBnASiFNEjhUfRBFeEhDi
QjYjMffnftJ2hYBnAEXiGfViDfLRDViIfOViFfNViJfTffJ2hZBnASiKPEjhUfRBFeEiCjUjPjNffnf
tJ2haBnASiFNEjhUfRBFeEhDiQjYjMffnftJ2hbBnAEXiGfViDfLRDViKfPViFfNCNViHfUVRfWnnff
J2hcBnASiLQEjhUfRBFeEiSjHjIjUffnftJ2hdBnASiFNEjhUfRBFeEhDiQjYjMffnftJ2heBnAEXiG
fViDfLRDViLfQViFfNCNViJfTVQfVnnffJ2hfBnASiMREjhUfRBFeEiFjMjQjTffnftJ2iABnAEXiNf
ViAfIRDViCfKViMfRViDfLffJ2iBBnAShaFEjhbfRBFeMjDjPjOjUjFjOjUiMjBjZjFjSffnftJ2iCB
nAEXiNfVhVfCRDVhefGVhafFViAfIffJ2iDBnAEjiOfRDVhTfBVhVfCXiPfjiQfffJ2iHBnABXhRfjZ
fVhQfAnfZ2iJBnAXiRfXYfjZfAXhe4G0AiAQ4D0AhAhf4H0AiAiA4I0AiAiJ4B0AhAiB4J0AiAiC4K0
AiAiH4C0AhAiD4L0AiAiE4M0AiAiF4N0AiAiI4O0AiAiK4P0AiAiL4Q0AiAhQ40BiAiM4R0AiAhS40B
hAhT4B0AiAhV4C0AiAhX4D0AiAhY4E0AiAR4E0AhAha4F0AiAFSAzLjEjSjBjXiFjMjMjJjQjTjFiTA
2iKBM2iNBbyBn0ADJ2iOBnASiJACgfEXzDjDjPjTiUfjPfRBEjzHjSjBjEjJjBjOjTiVfRBVFfDffff
VCfCnnnftJ2iPBnASiHBCgfEXzDjTjJjOiWfjPfRBEjiVfRBVFfDffffVCfCnnnftZ2iRBnAARCViJf
AViHfBfAEiJ40BiAiH4B0AiAF4B0AhAC40BhACCAgeA2iSBM2iUBbyBn0ABZ2iVBnACGCgfVFfAXzCi
QiJiXfjPfnnnndlUABF40BhAB0AiVA2iWBM2iYBbyBn0ABZ2iZBnACGCgfVzFjUjIjFjUjBiYfAnndl
UXiXfjPfnnABiY40BhAB0AzHjEjFjHjSjFjFjTiZA2iaBM2ieBbyBn0AHJ2ifBnASzEjUjPjQiYiaAC
NXhEfXzGjCjPjVjOjEjTibfVgbfGnndBnftJ2jABnASzEjUjPjQiZicBCNXhFfXibfVgbfGnndBnftJ
2jBBnASzHjCjPjUjUjPjNiYidCCJXzBhSiefXibfVgbfGnndBnftJ2jCBnASzHjCjPjUjUjPjNiZifD
CJXzBhTjAfXibfVgbfGnndBnftJ2jEBnASzKjMjBjZjFjSiXjJjEjUjIjBEEjzIjQjBjSjTjFiJjOjU
jCfRBCJVidfCViafAnnffnftJ2jFBnASzLjMjBjZjFjSiIjFjJjHjIjUjDFEjjCfRBCJViffDVicfBn
nffnftZ2jHBnAWzGiPjCjKjFjDjUjECQVjBfERVjDfFAHgb40BhAia40BiAic4B0AiAid4C0AiAif4D
0AiAjB4E0AiAjD4F0AiABGALA2jIBBOAbBn0AKJBnASzGiViJifjSjFjTjFyBne2hFGjEjJjBjMjPjH
jbhAjUjFjYjUhahAhHiSjPjUjBjUjFiNjFhAhThHhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhNhRh
MhAhNhRidhMKJJJJJjDjPjOjUjSjPjMjThahAiQjBjOjFjMhAjbhAjUjFjYjUhahHiQjSjPjQjFjSjU
jJjFjThHhMhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjDjPjMjVjNjOhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOjNjFjOjUhah
HjGjJjMjMhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjSjJjHjIjUhHhMKJJJJJJjTjUjFjQjThah
AiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMKJJJJJJJjMjBjCjFjMhahAiTjU
jBjUjJjDiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiDjPjQjJjFjThahHjdhMKJJJJJJJjTjMjJjEjFjShahAiTj
MjJjEjFjShAjbjWjBjMjVjFhahRhShMhAjNjBjYjWjBjMjVjFhahXhShMhAjNjJjOjWjBjMjVjFhahQ
hMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhRhVhQhMhAhNhRidjdhMKJJJJJJJjUjYjUhahAiFjEjJj
UiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHhRhShHhMhAjDjIjBjSjBjDjUjFjSjThahAhWjdhMKJJJJJJjdhMKJJ
JJJJjSjBjEjJjVjThahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAKJJJJ
JJJjMjBjCjFjMhahAiTjUjBjUjJjDiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiSjBjEjJjVjThahHjdhMKJJJJJ
JJjTjMjJjEjFjShahAiTjMjJjEjFjShAjbjWjBjMjVjFhahQhMhAjNjBjYjWjBjMjVjFhahRhQhQhQh
MhAjNjJjOjWjBjMjVjFhahQhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhRhVhQhMhAhNhRidjdhMKJ
JJJJJJjUjYjUhahAiFjEjJjUiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHhQhAjQjYhHhMhAjDjIjBjSjBjDjUjFj
SjThahAhWjdhMKJJJJJJjdhMKJJJJJJjSjPjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjB
jUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAKJJJJJJJjMjBjCjFjMhahAiTjUjBjUjJjDiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjFjYj
UhahHiSjPjUjBjUjJjPjOhahHjdhMKJJJJJJJjTjMjJjEjFjShahAiTjMjJjEjFjShAjbjWjBjMjVjF
hahQhMhAjNjBjYjWjBjMjVjFhahThWhQhMhAjNjJjOjWjBjMjVjFhahNhThWhQhMhAjQjSjFjGjFjSj
SjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhRhVhQhMhAhNhRidjdhMKJJJJJJJjUjYjUhahAiFjEjJjUiUjFjYjUhAjbjUjF
jYjUhahHhQ2maChHhMhAjDjIjBjSjBjDjUjFjSjThahAhWjdhMKJJJJJJjdhMKJJJJJjdKJJJJJjPjQ
jUjJjPjOjThahAiQjBjOjFjMhAjbhAjUjFjYjUhahHiPjQjUjJjPjOjThHhMhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUj
JjPjOhahAhHjDjPjMjVjNjOhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOjNjFjOjUhahHjGjJjMjMhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjI
jJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjMjFjGjUhHhMKJJJJJJjSjPjXhRhahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJ
jPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjMjFjGjUhHhMKJJJJJJJjSjPjUj
BjUjFiSjFjMjBjUjJjWjFiQjBjUjIhahAiDjIjFjDjLjCjPjYhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiSjPjUjBjUjFhA
iSjFjMjBjUjJjWjFhAjUjPhAiDjFjOjUjFjShHhMhAjWjBjMjVjFhahAjUjSjVjFjdhMKJJJJJJJjHj
SjPjVjQiMjBjZjFjSjThahAiDjIjFjDjLjCjPjYhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiHjSjPjVjQhAiMjBjZjFjSjT
hHhMhAjWjBjMjVjFhahAjUjSjVjFjdhMKJJJJJJjdKJJJJJJjSjPjXhShahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbjPjSj
JjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOiDjIjJjMjEjSjFjOhahHjMjFjGjUhHhMKJ
JJJJJJjTjBjWjFiPjSjJjHjJjOjBjMhahAiDjIjFjDjLjCjPjYhAjbjUjFjYjUhahHiTjBjWjFhAiPj
SjJjHjJjOjBjMhAiMjBjZjFjShHjdhMKJJJJJJjdKJJJJJjdKJJJJJjCjVjUjUjPjOjThahAiHjSjPj
VjQjbhAjPjSjJjFjOjUjBjUjJjPjOhahAhHjSjPjXhHhMhAjBjMjJjHjOjNjFjOjUhahHjDjFjOjUjF
jShHhMKJJJJJJjBjCjPjVjUifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjYjUhahAhHhfhHhMhAjQjSjF
jGjFjSjSjFjEiTjJjajFhaibhVhQhMhNhRidjdhMKJJJJJJjHjSjPjVjQhahAiHjSjPjVjQhAjbhAjN
jBjSjHjJjOjThaibhWhQhMhNhRhMhNhRhMhNhRidhMKJJJJJJJjPjLifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOh
AjbjUjFjYjUhahHiPiLhHjdhMKJJJJJJJjDjBjOjDjFjMifjCjUjOhahAiCjVjUjUjPjOhAjbjUjFjY
jUhahHiDjBjOjDjFjMhHjdhMKJJJJJJjdKJJJJJjdKJJJJjdftghGbyBn0ACbhHn0AMJhHnASzDjXjJ
jOjGyBEjzGiXjJjOjEjPjXjHfRBVjFfyBftnftJhInASzIjTjUjFjQjTifjTjMjIyBXzGjTjMjJjEjF
jSjJfXHfXzIjDjPjOjUjSjPjMjTjKfVjGfyBnftJhJnASzJjTjUjFjQjTifjUjYjUjLyBXzDjUjYjUj
MfXHfXjKfVjGfyBnftJhLnASzJjSjBjEjJjVjTifjTjMjNyBXjJfXCfXjKfVjGfyBnftJhMnASzKjSj
BjEjJjVjTifjUjYjUjOyBXjMfXCfXjKfVjGfyBnftJhOnASzLjSjPjUjBjUjJjPjOifjTjMjPyBXjJf
XzIjSjPjUjBjUjJjPjOjQfXjKfVjGfyBnftJhPnASzMjSjPjUjBjUjJjPjOifjUjYjUjRyBXjMfXjQf
XjKfVjGfyBnftJhRnAShHyBXhHfXzEjSjPjXhRjSfXzHjPjQjUjJjPjOjTjTfVjGfyBnftJhSnAShNy
BXhNfXzEjSjPjXhSjUfXjTfVjGfyBnftJhTnASgcyBXgcfXjSfXjTfVjGfyBnftJhVnASzJjBjCjPjV
jUifjCjUjOjVyBXjVfXzHjCjVjUjUjPjOjTjWfVjGfyBnftJhWnASzLjQjSjFjWjJjFjXifjCjUjOjX
yBXjXfXjWfVjGfyBnftbhan0ADJhanASMyBXiRfXYfjZfnftJhbnASzKjBiMjBjZjFjSiTjJjajFjYy
BEjLfRBVMfyBffnftJhcnASzFjTjJjajFjTjZyBARCXQfVjYfyBXRfVjYfyBfnftABnzBjFjanbyBn0
ABJhenAEjzFjBjMjFjSjUjbfRBjjafffJiBnABXzHjPjOiDjMjJjDjLjcfVjVfyBNyBnAMiBbyBn0AB
JiCnAEjjbfRBFeiJiSjPjUjBjUjFhAiNjFhAhThOhQKiDjSjFjBjUjFjEhAjCjZhAiLjBjNjJjMhAiL
jIjBjEjFjZjFjWhAhIiAjEjBjSjLjXjBjSjLhJKjCjMjPjHhOjLjBjNhYhYhOjDjPjNKlJhAhShQhRh
Uff0DzAjdCiDnfJiInABXzKjPjOiDjIjBjOjHjJjOjHjefVjIfyBNyBnAMiIbyBn0ACJiJnABXzFjWj
BjMjVjFjffezEjUjIjJjTkAfEXzFjSjPjVjOjEkBfjPfRBXjffekAfffnfJiKnABXzEjUjFjYjUkCfj
jLfXjffekAfnf0DjdCiLnfJiNnABXzIjPjOiDjIjBjOjHjFkDfVjLfyBNyBnAMiNbyBn0AFJiOnABXk
CfekAfEjjCfRBXkCfekAfffnfOiQbyiRn0ABJiRnABXkCfekAfXjffjjIfnfAEjzFjJjTiOjBiOkEfR
BXkCfekAfffnOiUbyiVn0ABJiVnABXkCfekAfXzIjNjBjYjWjBjMjVjFkFfjjIfnfACzBhekGXkCfek
AfXkFfjjIfnnnOiYbyiZn0ABJiZnABXkCfekAfXzIjNjJjOjWjBjMjVjFkHfjjIfnfACUXkCfekAfXk
HfjjIfnnnJicnABXjffjjIfXkCfekAfnf0DjdCidnfJjBnABXjefVjNfyBNyBnAMjBbyBn0ACJjCnAB
XjffekAfEXkBfjPfRBXjffekAfffnfJjDnABXkCfjjOfCNXjffekAfnneDhAjQjYnf0DjdCjEnfJjGn
ABXkDfVjOfyBNyBnAMjGbyBn0AGJjHnABXkCfekAfEjjCfRBXkCfekAfffnfOjJbyjKn0ABJjKnABXk
CfekAfXjffjjNfnfAEjkEfRBXkCfekAfffnOjNbyjOn0ABJjOnABXkCfekAfXkFfjjNfnfACkGXkCfe
kAfXkFfjjNfnnnOjRbyjSn0ABJjSnABXkCfekAfXkHfjjNfnfACUXkCfekAfXkHfjjNfnnnJjVnABXj
ffjjNfXkCfekAfnfJjWnABXkCfekAfCNnnneDhAjQjYnt0DjdCjYnfJjcnABXjefVjPfyBNyBnAMjcb
yBn0ACJjdnABXjffekAfEXkBfjPfRBXjffekAfffnfJjenABXkCfjjRfCNXjffekAfnneB2maCnf0Dj
dCkAnfJkCnABXkDfVjRfyBNyBnAMkCbyBn0AGJkDnABXkCfekAfEjjCfRBXkCfekAfffnfOkFbykGn0
ABJkGnABXkCfekAfXjffjjPfnfAEjkEfRBXkCfekAfffnOkJbykKn0ABJkKnABXkCfekAfXkFfjjPfn
fACkGXkCfekAfXkFfjjPfnnnOkNbykOn0ABJkOnABXkCfekAfXkHfjjPfnfACUXkCfekAfXkHfjjPfn
nnJkRnABXjffjjPfXkCfekAfnfJkSnABXkCfekAfCNnnneB2maCnt0DjdCkUnfOkabykdn0ABJkdnAE
XzOjTjVjTjQjFjOjEiIjJjTjUjPjSjZkIfXYfjZfRCFehbibiLiBiNidhAiSjPjUjBjUjFiNjFhAhTh
AiTjDjSjJjQjUhAhIiMjFjBjSjOhAjNjPjSjFhahAjIjUjUjQhahPhPjCjMjPjHhOjLjBjNhYhYhOjD
jPjNhJFekGjSjPjUjBjUjFiNjFhThIjBiMjBjZjFjShMhAjTjUjFjQjTifjTjMhOjWjBjMjVjFhMhAj
SjBjEjJjVjTifjTjMhOjWjBjMjVjFhMhAjSjPjUjBjUjJjPjOifjTjMhOjWjBjMjVjFhMhAjSjPjUjB
jUjFiSjFjMjBjUjJjWjFiQjBjUjIhOjWjBjMjVjFhMhAjTjBjWjFiPjSjJjHjJjOjBjMhOjWjBjMjVj
FhMhAjHjSjPjVjQiMjBjZjFjSjThOjWjBjMjVjFhJffACzChdhdkJEXzEjTjIjPjXkKfVjGfyBnfnnd
BnACkJXzGjMjBjZjFjSjTkLfXiRfXYfjZfjzJjVjOjEjFjGjJjOjFjEkMfnnbylDn0ABJlDnAEjjbfR
BFehBiPjQjQjThBKiQjMjFjBjTjFhAjTjFjMjFjDjUhAjSjFjHjVjMjBjShAjMjBjZjFjSffAQjY4O0
AiAjG4B0AiAjF40BiAjI4C0AiAjL4D0AiAjN4E0AiAjO4F0AiAjP4G0AiAjR4H0AiAhH4I0AiAhN4J0
AiAgc4K0AiAjV4L0AiAjX4M0AiAjZ4P0AiAM4N0AiAAQAjdByB
```

Comment: Seems wonderful, unfortunately, it doesn't work with my CS5 (even if it is reported to work with this version on the page!)

Comment: @Basj Added a second way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joonas, that's wonderful! I edited and added a few remarks about shortcuts, and a way to set precise coordinates for the reference point. Last thing: what soft/what format (gif?avi?gifv) do you use for such easy-to-do animated screenshots / gif ?

Comment: @Basj Good. --- I didn't exactly make it easy for myself this time. I've been using [Gif Recorder](http://bit.ly/GifRecorder) when I know that I'm going to record a simple gif. It's just that this time I decided to add the annotations. So... I  imported the gif to Photoshop, converted to timeline animation, added the annotations and saved as gif. There is also [GiFox](http://gifox.io/). More advanced settings, but doesn't record clicks (yet). I could have also just used [QuickTime](http://apple.co/2ds4JZB) to record the screen. You can't add annotations directly with it. It also doesn't

Comment: export to gif, so you need to use a third party application to convert to gif (like PS for instance). There are a few easy to use gif converters on mac: [Gif Brewery](http://gifbrewery.com/) and [Gif Rocket](http://www.gifrocket.com/). You can also use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) to convert video files to gif. Perhaps the quickest/simplest workflow would be to use [Screenflow 6](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow). SF6 supports gif export. --- I've fallen out of touch with many Windows applications, but  maybe [Camtasia studio](http://bit.ly/2ds7zOa) or [SnagIt](http://bit.ly/2ds77j7).