# Using Photoshop arrays to multiply a layer around a center point

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been researching for hours seeking a decent explanation on **Photoshop arrays** for 2020+ PS versions. Several tutorials explain the obvious about setting the center point. However, all tutorial's shortkeys and next steps fail somehow.

How can I create a selected number of circles to occupy the outer rim in a perfectly symmetrical way without manually adding each one?

[image]

Also is there a way to place the center point perfectly? (like by number or direct center etc)

Comment: To be honest, I don't think Photoshop is the right software for this kind of work. It would be much easier in Adobe Illustrator, or other vector software.

Comment: Great answer there @Joonas. However the last step, repeating with `Cmd/Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `T`, does not create new layers. It only moves the original layer around the center point. Do you know what detail I'm missing?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is... maybe your `Alt` key doesn't work for some reason. The shortcut is the same as doing `Edit > Transform > Again`. Although the shortcut is actually: `Cdm+Shift+T`. When you add the `Alt` modifier, it should enable copying(or duplicating) like with many other functions/apps. It's basically the same as when you move layer(s) inside the document with the `move tool`, you can make a copy at the same time by holding down `Alt`. Or if you move the layer with arrow keys and hold down `Alt`. Try doing that and see if it works. If not, that's the problem.

Comment: Did you try the script though? It's way better than doing it manually like this. The OP of the other question said it didn't work, but I've had no issues using it (CS 5 - CC 2020). I would also suggest Illustrator. It has: [`Effect > Distord & Transform > Transform...`](https://youtu.be/Wp55aap1g3s?t=70). This is a little easier to use because it has a preview. It's very common to do something in another application and bring it back to the core application... Nothing wrong with that workflow... If you have access to Illustrator.

Comment: Thank you for your persistence in helping @Joonas. However, the RotateMe jsx is no longer hosted properly and it cannot be downloaded. Also I commonly use `alt` to duplicate. But I believe holding `shift` must be turning `alt` into `option` thus no duplication.

Comment: Can you try moving layer contents with the move tool active by using arrow keys with the shortcut `Shift+Alt+Arrow key`. `Alt` modifier makes a copy and `Shift` modifier moves the layer by 10px. If the `Shift+Alt` combo doesn't work then that probably is the reason. It won't tell us why exactly, but it will confirm that it's not the specific shortcut, but rather the combination of `Shift` and `Alt`. — I edited [my answer in that other post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/78288/2332) to include the script code.