# How do I create this concentric Circle pattern?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

[image]

Pattern is the innermost concentric ring made using right parentheses  { ")))))))...."  }.

Comment: Look at this post: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76195/how-can-i-create-a-circle-with-a-circles-border-regularly  
You should easily be able to solve it by tweaking the answer a little.
Edit: You should do this in Illustrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Illustrator:

1. Type a left bracket/parenthesis, convert to outlines, and rotate it -90°
2. Click and drag it into the brushes panel, and choose the option to make a Pattern Brush
3. Use the settings shown below
4. Apply the brush to a circle with no fill

[image]